# How to bring India financial years base on month using SQL select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need financial year as below format. in India financial year runs from `1 April` to `31 March` in every year.

```
1. Example 1 April 2018 to 31 march 2019 (2018 - 2019).
2. Example 1 April 2019 to 31 march 2020 (2019 - 2020).
```

I want below output and select query need below columns from 2018 to currently date, if the new April month starts then again new dropdown value should come, example `2020` year past then if current month `April 2021` then the new dropdown value `2021 - 2022` should come like that so on.

```
Year       FinancialYear
------------------------
2018       2018-2019 
2019       2019-2020
```

Comment: which dbms product are you using?

Comment: sql-server-2008-r2. @Atk

Comment: Use recursive CTE for this

Comment: No idea please can post logic or answer. @Atk

Comment: Just wait a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its a bit lengthy, but it will work.

```
drop table if exists #asa
declare @getdate datetime='2025-04-06 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @FromDate varchar(30),@ToDate varchar(30),@datediff2018 INT=CONVERT(INT,datediff(day,'2017-04-01',@getdate)/365.25)


create table #asa
(
Year varchar(10),
FY varchar(20)
)
WHILE(@datediff2018>0)
BEGIN
    IF(MONTH(@getdate)>=4 AND MONTH(@getdate)<=12)
    BEGIN
    SET @FromDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(dateadd(year,-@datediff2018+1,@getdate)))+'-04-01'
    END
    ELSE IF(MONTH(@getdate)>=1 AND MONTH(@getdate)<=3)
    BEGIN
    SET @FromDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(dateadd(year,-@datediff2018+1,@getdate))-1)+'-04-01'
    END

    IF(MONTH(@getdate)>=4 AND MONTH(@getdate)<=12)
    BEGIN
    SET @ToDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(dateadd(year,-@datediff2018+1,@getdate))+1)+'-03-31'
    END
    ELSE IF(MONTH(@getdate)>=1 AND MONTH(@getdate)<=3)
    BEGIN
    SET @ToDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(dateadd(year,-@datediff2018+1,@getdate)))+'-03-31'
    END

    insert into #asa
    select YEAR(@FromDate),CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(@FromDate))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(@ToDate))
    set @datediff2018=@datediff2018-1
END
select * from #asa
```

Comment: IF 1 april 2020 will come then new row will add or not? like 2020 2020-2021. @Atk

Comment: change your server date to 01 april 2020 and test

Comment: I have updated my answer so that you can test it, just put whatever date you want in variable @getdate and check

Comment: yes but it will work fine. there were lots of permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `datefromparts()` function as shown below. Here is the official documentation of [DATEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This function returns a date value that maps to the specified year, month, and day values.

Syntax

```
DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )
```

Below is the implementation for you.

```
create table FinancialYear (Year int)
insert into FinancialYear values (2018), (2019), (2020)

Select Year, 
       Cast(Year as Varchar(4)) + '-' + Cast(year + 1 as varchar(4)) as FinancialYear
       ,datefromparts(year, 4, 1) as [StartingDate]
       ,datefromparts(year + 1 , 3, 31) as [EndingDate] 
from FinancialYear
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff0bf826d6227a7073d216f62556a21c)

The output is as shown in the below image.

[image]

There is an alternative by using `cte` you do not need table as shown below.

```
-- Define start and end limits
Declare @start int, @end int
Select @start = 2018, -- As you want
@end = year(getdate()) --Current Year

;With NumberSequence( Year ) as
(
    Select @start as Year
        union all
    Select Year + 1
        from NumberSequence
        where Year < @end
)

--Select result
Select Year, 
       Cast(Year as Varchar(4)) + '-' + Cast(year + 1 as varchar(4)) as FinancialYear
       ,datefromparts(year, 4, 1) as [StartingDate]
       ,datefromparts(year + 1 , 3, 31) as [EndingDate] 
from NumberSequence Option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Here is the [Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=787b69d61c65fc929b134b92682ffa6c).

**Edit**

If you are using SQL Server 2005 then your query will be as shown below.

```
insert into FinancialYear values (2018)
insert into FinancialYear values (2019)
insert into FinancialYear values (2020)

Select Year, 
       Cast(Year as Varchar(4)) + '-' + Cast(year + 1 as varchar(4)) as FinancialYear
       ,CAST(Convert(Varchar(4), year) + '-' + '4' + '-' + '1' as DATETime) as [StartingDate]
       ,CAST(Convert(Varchar(4), year + 1) + '-' + '3' + '-' + '31' as DateTime) as [EndingDate] 
from FinancialYear
```

If you want to exclude the financial year when month number is either `Jan`, `Fab` or `March` then you can write where condition for that as below.

```
Select Year, 
       Cast(Year as Varchar(4)) + '-' + Cast(year + 1 as varchar(4)) as FinancialYear
       ,CAST(Convert(Varchar(4), year) + '-' + '4' + '-' + '1' as DATETime) as [StartingDate]
       ,CAST(Convert(Varchar(4), year + 1) + '-' + '3' + '-' + '31' as DateTime) as [EndingDate] 
from FinancialYear
where (
    (ISNULL(month(getdate()), 0) >= 4 ) 
    OR 
    (ISNULL(month(getdate()), 0) < 4 AND Year < year(getdate()))
    )
```

Comment: I don't want to create table direct select query. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan Then what you want? You can insert this result in a table. You can pass the where condition in select for the dropdown like - where year <= year(getdate()).

Comment: if next years come again i have insert manually 2021 like that, can we bring directly is posible. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: You can do it for now and pass the where condition as said in my previous comment so it will not appear. You can do it manually or create a SQL server job to insert year also.

Comment: i am getting error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 18
'datefromparts' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan I have edited my answer for lower version of SQL Server.

Comment: bro i want answer like atk direct select query my requirement is like that, thank you for your effort and i upvoted your answer already. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan I had already update for direct select using cte please check this extracted from my answer. There is no need of multiple if..else.. here. - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97a06efc95ffc334e4331c98293cf338

Comment: 2020 2020-2021 2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 2021-03-31 00:00:00.000 the last row should not come because 2020 financial year not started. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: Then you can pass where condition at last line  as - where year < year(getdate()).

Comment: After 1 April 2020 it should come becuase 2020 finacial year start from that month only na. @Suraj Kumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207251/discussion-between-suraj-kumar-and-mohd-mazhar-khan).

Answer (score 1):

this will gives you current & previous financial year. It uses [Table Value Contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate 2 rows

```
select  datename(year, dateadd(month, -3, [date])) as [Year],
        datename(year, dateadd(month, -3, [date])) 
        + '-' + 
        datename(year, dateadd(month, +9, [date])) as [FinancialYear]
from    (
            values 
            (dateadd(year, -1, getdate())), -- previous fy
            (getdate())                     -- current financial year
        ) as fy ([date])
order by [date]
```

Comment: Your output is different what i asked. @Squirrel

Comment: added the `Year` column

Comment: IF 1 april 2020 will come then new row will add or not? like  2020   2020-2021.@Squirrel

Comment: yes. you can replace `getdate()` with that date and try

Comment: Please update full answer will help to me. @Squirrel

Comment: that is already the working query. I don't understand what do you mean by `full answer`

Comment: IF 1 april 2020 will come then new row will add or not? like 2020 2020-2021 i have confused about.  total answer will like Year       FinancialYear
2018       2018-2019 
2019       2019-2020
2020       2020-2021           @Squirrel